# Basic flask form handling

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a basic form in Flask that will take in the input, manipulate it and then return the output. I am running into the issue that when I am running the terminal and trying to make my app work on the http://127.0.0.1:5000/ server, the files are not visible. Not sure where the bug is?

This is how I have my files organized:

/Users/eas/Desktop/grota/templates/index.html

/Users/eas/Desktop/grota/templates/age.html

/Users/eas/Desktop/grota/app.py

This is the app.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/send',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def send():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        age = request.form['age']
        return render_template('age.html',age=age)
    return render_template('index.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

This is the index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
     <h1>How old are you?</h1>
    <form method="POST" action = "/send">
      <div class = "form-group">
        <input type="text" name = "age">
      </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

This is the age.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
      <h1>Your age is{{age}}</h1>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

While looking for a problem, which I try to solve I found your question. For a solution that includes full code (with py and 2 HTML files) you can see my repl.it : https://repl.it/@AlperenAtik/NaturalShortActivecell#main.py

The problems are:

1. In the first function, you routed your loop to "/send" page. This is why your send page did not appear. The route of the first function needs to be "/"
2. In the index file, the source route was shown as '/send'. Whenever I changed it to /  the script worked without a problem
3. The other commentators already mentioned your triggering function has an indentation mistake. When host and port added appropriately, your script would work.

for ones who love the harder way- seeing things in stackoverflow- not in action, I am adding the codeblocks. Enjoy.

for main.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def send():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        age = request.form['age']
        return render_template('age.html',age=age)
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8080
```

I left the host as '0.0.0.0' and port as 8080. If you are running Python on a terminal, you may try (host = '127.0.0.1', port:5000').

for templates/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
     <h1>How old are you?</h1>
    <form method="POST" action = "/">
      <div class = "form-group">
        <input type="text" name = "age">
      </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

for templates/age.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
      <h1>Your age is {{age}}</h1>
  </body>
```

Comment: Maybe could you insert the reply within stackoverflow to avoid to insert a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try going here: http://127.0.0.1:5000/send

If that doesn't work, what error are you getting in either your console or in your browser?

EDIT:

I just tried it, and it worked. Try reloading the page in a new tab in your browser, and see if it still occurs. This error has to do with the naming of your inputs on the webpage and the way you index your form with `request.form['age']`

Comment: Bad Request
I went to the http://127.0.0.1:5000/send and I got the following error:
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the root route.

Or you open http://127.0.0.1:5000/send

Or you could use this quick and dirty fix (as you see in decorators now both / and /send are taken into account):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods = ['GET'])
@app.route('/send',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def send():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        age = request.form['age']
        return render_template('age.html',age=age)
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If you do not handle the '/' route nothing will happen when you open http://127.0.0.1

If you explain more clearly what is the result that you want to obtain I can help better.

Comment: I wrote backend python scripts that I want to run on the user input and return the value obtained to the user. The code above is a simplified version of what I want to do, it aims at asking the user for age and printing it back. I still get the following error even after your corrections in the code: Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: Code perfectly works on my pc.
Could it be a simple caching problem?
Did you try deleting cache or using a different browser?

Comment: What do you see in python terminal window?

Comment: TemplateNotFound: index.html
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2018 20:42:04] "GET /send HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: did you put your index.html into templates folder (created in the script path)?